# Powershell rename files add brackets

Tags: powershell

I have different files that are now called 455668446854 for example each file has its own number.
What I need to do is that it renames the file to this:
[455][668][446854]

What is the best way to do this via powershell?
I have a couple 100 files in the same directory that all need to be converted.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code.

Comment: brackets [or braces or parens] can cause odd problems with code that handles file names. could you use hyphens instead?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey unfortantly not the program that needs to read the file only allows [] but it doesnt matter since the files will be deleted after the program opened the files.

Comment: @klaas123 - thanks for the feedback! [*grin*] please take a look at my Answer. it shows three ways to modify a string of numbers.

Comment: Brackets are wildcards in powershell.  It's going to be harder to manage after you do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following assuming you are currently in the directory that contains the files:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\[0-9]*[0-9] -File |
   Where Name -match '^\d+$' |
       Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)','[$1][$2][$3]'} -WhatIf
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` parameter for the rename operation to occur.

**Explanation:**

[Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) `-Path` parameter supports wildcards. The purpose of the `.\[0-9]*[0-9]` is to look into the current directory (`.`) and find items that begin and end with a number. `-File` returns only files. This is simply to minimize the work of the more inefficient `Where` statement.

`^\d+$` is a regex expression used in conjunction with the `-match` operator in this case. It simply means return files that have names that begin (`^`) with one or more (`+`) numbers (`\d`) and ends (`$`) following those numbers.

The `Name` or `BaseName` property should match here since you don't have file extensions in your post. If you do have file extensions, then the `BaseName` property will need to be used instead.

The `-replace` operation replaces three numbers (`\d{3}`), three numbers, and the remaining numbers with brackets around each group. Since we use `()` around the regex mechanisms, we create capture groups named 1,2,3 starting from left to right. The replace string allows us to manipulate to a somewhat limited degree (Windows PowerShell only since Core has more options) the output.

Comment: Thank you maybe you can help me with this one too:
I have this filename:  2129962 0162-206 837-861 HP I that need to be converted to this: [750][0162][0206][HP][837][861]

Comment: That one seems trickier and requires more explanation on your part. Where does the `750` come from? Why does the `206` become `0206`?

Answer (score 0):

this is just working with the strings ... you will need to work with the `.BaseName` property if you use actual `fileinfo` objects. it uses both hyphens [safer for file names than brackets] and brackets. [*grin*]

the code demos 3 methods as the comments list.

```
$InStuff = '111222333333'

'using the "-f" format string operator ...'
'{0:###-###-######}' -f [int64]$InStuff
'{0:[###][###][######]}' -f [int64]$InStuff
'=' * 30
'using the "-replace" operator with a regex pattern ...'
$InStuff -replace '(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{6})', '$1-$2-$3'
$InStuff -replace '(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{6})', '[$1][$2][$3]'
'=' * 30
# do the insert last-first to avoid changing the the insert position
'using the ".Insert()" string method ...'
$InStuff.Insert(6, '-').Insert(3, '-')
$InStuff.Insert(12, ']').Insert(6, '[').Insert(6, ']').Insert(3, '[').Insert(3, ']').Insert(0, '[')
''
```

output ...

```
using the "-f" format string operator ...
111-222-333333
[111][222][333333]
==============================
using the "-replace" operator with a regex pattern ...
111-222-333333
[111][222][333333]
==============================
using the ".Insert()" string method ...
111-222-333333
[111][222][333333]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Substring Method You can try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "FolderPath" | Foreach {
  $p1 = $_.Name.ToString().SubString(0,3)
  $p2 = $_.Name.ToString().SubString(3,3)
  $p3 = $_.Name.ToString().SubString(6,6)
  Rename-Item -Path $_ -NewName "`[$($p1)`]`[$($p2)`]`[$($p3)`]"
}
```